# Join pandas dataframes according to common index value only

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframes (this is just test data), in real samples, I have index values that are repeated a few times inside dataframe 1 and dataframe 2 - this causes the repeated/duplicate rows inside final dataframe.

**DataFrame 1:**

```
    pd.DataFrame({'id': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 4, 4: 5, 5: 6, 6: 7, 7: 8, 8: 9, 9: 10},
     'first_name': {0: 'Jennee',
      1: 'Dagny',
      2: 'Correy',
      3: 'Pall',
      4: 'Julie',
      5: 'Janene',
      6: 'Lemmy',
      7: 'Coleman',
      8: 'Beck',
      9: 'Che'},
     'last_name': {0: 'Strelitzki',
      1: 'Dunsire',
      2: 'Wickrath',
      3: 'Jopp',
      4: 'Gheeraert',
      5: 'Gawith',
      6: 'Farrow',
      7: 'Legging',
      8: 'Beckwith',
      9: 'Burgoin'},
     'email': {0: 'jstrelitzki0@google.de',
      1: 'ddunsire1@geocities.com',
      2: 'cwickrath2@github.com',
      3: 'pjopp3@infoseek.co.jp',
      4: 'jgheeraert4@theatlantic.com',
      5: 'jgawith5@sciencedirect.com',
      6: 'lfarrow6@wikimedia.org',
      7: 'clegging7@businessinsider.com',
      8: 'bbeckwith8@zdnet.com',
      9: 'cburgoin9@reference.com'},
     'gender': {0: 'Male',
      1: 'Female',
      2: 'Female',
      3: 'Female',
      4: 'Female',
      5: 'Female',
      6: 'Male',
      7: 'Female',
      8: 'Polygender',
      9: 'Male'},
     'ip_address': {0: '8.99.68.120',
      1: '188.238.129.48',
      2: '87.159.243.249',
      3: '66.37.174.94',
      4: '233.77.128.104',
      5: '190.202.131.98',
      6: '84.175.231.196',
      7: '140.178.100.5',
      8: '81.211.179.167',
      9: '31.219.69.206'},
     'Boolean': {0: False,
      1: False,
      2: True,
      3: True,
      4: False,
      5: True,
      6: True,
      7: False,
      8: False,
      9: False}})
```

****DataFrame 2:****

```
pd.DataFrame({'id': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 4, 4: 5, 5: 6, 6: 7, 7: 8, 8: 9, 9: 10},
 'Model': {0: 2005,
  1: 2007,
  2: 2011,
  3: 2003,
  4: 1998,
  5: 1992,
  6: 1992,
  7: 1992,
  8: 2008,
  9: 1996},
 'Make': {0: 'Cadillac',
  1: 'Lexus',
  2: 'Dodge',
  3: 'Dodge',
  4: 'Oldsmobile',
  5: 'Volkswagen',
  6: 'Chevrolet',
  7: 'Suzuki',
  8: 'Ford',
  9: 'Mazda'},
 'Colour': {0: 'Red',
  1: 'Red',
  2: 'Crimson',
  3: 'Red',
  4: 'Purple',
  5: 'Crimson',
  6: 'Red',
  7: 'Aquamarine',
  8: 'Puce',
  9: 'Maroon'}})
```

The two dataframes should be connected based on common Index values found in both dataframes only. Which means, any index values that don't match in those two dataframes; should not appear in the final combined/merged dataframe.

I want to ensure that the final dataframe is unique, and only captures combinations of columns, based on unique Index values.

When I try using the following code, the output is supposed to 'inner join' based on the unique index found in both dataframes.

```
final = pd.merge(df1, df2, left_index=True, right_index=True)
```

However, when I try applying the above merge technique on my larger (other) pandas dataframes, there are many rows being repeated/duplicated multiple times. When the merging happpens a few times with more dataframes, the rows gets repeated very frequently, with the same Index value.

I am expecting to see one Index value returned per row (with all the column combinations from each dataframe).

I am not sure why this happens. I can confirm that there is nothing wrong with the datasets.

Is there a better technique of merging those two dataframes, based on only common index values, and at the same time ensure that I don't repeat any rows (with the same index) in my final dataframe ? I often find that this merging often creates a giant final CSV file around 20GB in size too. The source files are only around 15MB into total.

Any help is much appreciated.

My end output should look like this (please copy and use this as Pandas DF):

```
 pd.DataFrame({'id': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 4, 4: 5, 5: 6, 6: 7, 7: 8, 8: 9, 9: 10},
     'first_name': {0: 'Jennee',
      1: 'Dagny',
      2: 'Correy',
      3: 'Pall',
      4: 'Julie',
      5: 'Janene',
      6: 'Lemmy',
      7: 'Coleman',
      8: 'Beck',
      9: 'Che'},
     'last_name': {0: 'Strelitzki',
      1: 'Dunsire',
      2: 'Wickrath',
      3: 'Jopp',
      4: 'Gheeraert',
      5: 'Gawith',
      6: 'Farrow',
      7: 'Legging',
      8: 'Beckwith',
      9: 'Burgoin'},
     'email': {0: 'jstrelitzki0@google.de',
      1: 'ddunsire1@geocities.com',
      2: 'cwickrath2@github.com',
      3: 'pjopp3@infoseek.co.jp',
      4: 'jgheeraert4@theatlantic.com',
      5: 'jgawith5@sciencedirect.com',
      6: 'lfarrow6@wikimedia.org',
      7: 'clegging7@businessinsider.com',
      8: 'bbeckwith8@zdnet.com',
      9: 'cburgoin9@reference.com'},
     'gender': {0: 'Male',
      1: 'Female',
      2: 'Female',
      3: 'Female',
      4: 'Female',
      5: 'Female',
      6: 'Male',
      7: 'Female',
      8: 'Polygender',
      9: 'Male'},
     'ip_address': {0: '8.99.68.120',
      1: '188.238.129.48',
      2: '87.159.243.249',
      3: '66.37.174.94',
      4: '233.77.128.104',
      5: '190.202.131.98',
      6: '84.175.231.196',
      7: '140.178.100.5',
      8: '81.211.179.167',
      9: '31.219.69.206'},
     'Boolean': {0: False,
      1: False,
      2: True,
      3: True,
      4: False,
      5: True,
      6: True,
      7: False,
      8: False,
      9: False},
     'Model': {0: 2005,
      1: 2007,
      2: 2011,
      3: 2003,
      4: 1998,
      5: 1992,
      6: 1992,
      7: 1992,
      8: 2008,
      9: 1996},
     'Make': {0: 'Cadillac',
      1: 'Lexus',
      2: 'Dodge',
      3: 'Dodge',
      4: 'Oldsmobile',
      5: 'Volkswagen',
      6: 'Chevrolet',
      7: 'Suzuki',
      8: 'Ford',
      9: 'Mazda'},
     'Colour': {0: 'Red',
      1: 'Red',
      2: 'Crimson',
      3: 'Red',
      4: 'Purple',
      5: 'Crimson',
      6: 'Red',
      7: 'Aquamarine',
      8: 'Puce',
      9: 'Maroon'}})
```

Comment: Please provide the expected output for your sample.

Comment: Your index contain duplicates , so what is your unique definition ?

Comment: Now we need the corresponding input dataframes :)

Comment: In your example dataframes, you have no duplicate ID so the connection is one-to-one. There won't be any duplicates. A simple merge provides the expected output.

Answer (score 0):

This is expected behavior with non-unique idx values. Since you have 3 ID1 rows in one df and 2 ID1 in the other, you end up with 6 ID1 rows in your merged df. If you add `validate="one_to_one"` to pd.merge() you will get this Error. MergeError: Merge keys are not unique in either left or right dataset; not a one-to-one mergeAll other validations fail except for many to many.

If it makes sense for your data, you can use the left_on, and right_on parameters to find unique combinations and give you a one-to-one if that's what you're after.

Edit after your new data:

Now that you have unique ids, this should work for you. Notice it doesn't throw a validation error.

```
final = pd.merge(df1, df2, left_on=['id'], right_on=['id'], validate='one_to_one')
```

Comment: This is precisely the problem I am facing;
will using this (validate="one_to_one") help to resolve this issue or not ? I'm not sure how left_on/right_on could work, since there are unique index values in both dataframes.

Comment: FWIW, merging on id assumes that there is a logical relationship between the id values in your dataframes. If you're trying to say this is not the case by stating, "there are unique index values in both dataframes" then you will likely need to figure out what the proper relationship is, and/or maybe restructure your data.